# How to expose only writable REST api with Spring Data REST?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Hi I am trying to develop REST api using **Spring boot + Spring Data JPA + Spring Data REST**

I want to expose only writable part of my User ( basically no GET or GET ALL ) entity which is as below

```
@Entity(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;

    @Column
    String login;

    @Column
    String password;

    @Column
    String username;

    @Column
    String address1;

    @Column
    String address2;

    @Column
    String city;

    @Column
    String state;

    @Column
    String zip;

    @Column
    String country;

    @Column
    String creditcard;


}
```

and datarepository is as below:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please refer link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169717/how-to-prevent-some-http-methods-from-being-exported-from-my-mongorepository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override and mark methods with the `@RestResource(exported = false)`.

The methods are

```
T findOne(ID id);         // /users/<ID>
Iterable<T> findAll();    // /users
Iterable<T> findAll(Iterable<ID> ids);
```

You will be getting the `405 Method Not Allowed` HTTP status for all `GET` requests to the repository.

---

Hint: [It is not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735543/column-annotation-absolutly-necessary-in-jpa) to mark fields with the `@Column` to make them reflected as database columns.